# Creating a html-form and got problems with the width

Tags: html, css, forms

i want to create a simple survey-form and got problems with the width.
The textfield is about 10px larger then the survey-form-box i created. I dont get it i set it to width: 100% in the css-file. Where is the problem?

```css
.survey-form {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 30%;
  margin-right: 30%;
  background: blue;
}

.form-control {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="survey-form">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input class="name form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name" />
  </form>
</body>
<html>
```

[The width from the textfield is not the same as the blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWnBR.jpg)

Comment: your class "`name form-control`" does not exist in your css. And I would to suggest not to use white spaces in html specifiers like class names and ids. Where did you include your stylesheet?

Comment: The OP had the class form-control in the css, and you can add multiple class for an element

Answer (score 3):

You should assign `box-sizing` property in `.form-control`

```
.form-control {
      width: 100%;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

FYI

1. [CSS Box Model](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)
2. [CSS box-sizing Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

Comment: or add it into a general selector

Answer (score 0):

you can use **box-sizing**

```css
.survey-form {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 30%;
    margin-right: 30%;
    background: blue;
    position:relative;
}

.form-control{
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Bin</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form class="survey-form">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input class="name form-control" type="text" placeholder="Name"/>
        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```